# Join query in laravel with data manipulation send to view

Tags: laravel, join, view, php-carbon

I am having 2 tables, `users` and `profiledetails`

I am able to run Join query and access the data and send to view.

But when I am manipulation the field 'dob' (date format) in `profiledetails` table. No Success, Please check the code below ,

`webpagesConroller`:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
        ->join('profiledetails', 'users.id', '=', 'profiledetails.user_id')  
        ->select('users.*', 'profiledetails.dob')
        ->get();
    $age = $users->dob->diffInYears(Carbon::now());         
    return view('webpages.index',compact('users'))->with($age);
```

`View:`

```
<li class="cate_head">Age : {{ $age}}</li>
```

Error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

I have model `Profiledetails` added the mutators as below,

```
  public function getAge(){

       return $this->dob->diffInYears(Carbon::now());            

    }

    public function getDOB(){
        return $this->dob->format('d-m-Y');
    }
```

Can I not use this method on another controller for Ex- webpagesController, If yes How.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a raw query, the data returned is not an object but an array with the data.

Also you did not limit the query, meaning it could return multiple rows.
You'll probably need to get the data from the $users as:

```
//with the possibily of multiple rows. Index is the row which has to be used
$users[index]['dob']

//when you are sure it only returns one row
$users[0]['dob'] // or $users['dob'] not sure as of the moment
```

You want to check the differences with Carbon.
So you will probably need to make a Carbon object of the dob result and check it against the Carbon::now.

```
$age = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $users[0]['dob'])->diffForHumans();      
// diffForHumans() uses the local time
```

Note that this only gets the age for one row (the index or the first because of [0]).

If you want to do it for every row use a for or foreach where you set the $users->age for every $user. But as these are not object/models but raw data, this will not work.

Hope this helps your question a bit